# google analytic track sub domain error

Tags: joomla, google-analytics, joomla2.5

I have two different joomla website in different folder with different sub domain.

for example,
public_html/chinese
and
public_html/english

domain preview
`http://chinese.mydomain.com`
and
`http://english.mydomain.com`

I wish to track these two websites separately in google analytic. As usual I created an account at first, and create two web property to serve both website.

The two web property details as below

```
Property ID: UA-XXXXXXX-1
Default URL: http://chinese.mydomain.com
```

tracking code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

and

```
Property ID: UA-XXXXXXX-2
Default URL: http://english.mydomain.com
```

tracking code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-2']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

both of the sites show "Status: Tracking Not Installed". I am totally confused and there isn't any clue whats going on.

Durin debugging after  the last line of the code appears the following message

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

I didn't install any GA code in my main domain www.mydomain.com because it just serve at redirect page to my sub domain. I hope this doesn't cause any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have gone about it in the wrong way, don't have two separate tracking codes, you need one.

Login to GA, then select on of the Accounts you have created, then Admin then you need to create 2 profiles, one for chinese. and one for english. You'll notice that you only have the one tracking code to then implement, and to review traffic for each site you simply need to click on the appropriate profile.

The way you have done it could potentially work without an issue, but you will be restricted in what you can do - and as I am taking it that this is localised versions of your site you don't want to be adding up in your head each time to find out the total visitors number.